# Display categories when i click on the category link

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code that dynamically displays the categories of books from the database. I want to now add another functionality, that if i click on any of the categories from the dropdown it should display the products from that category. But i already have a homepage which displays the books from database. I only want to be able to click on the category and change the products of that particular category.
Here's the code for the dropdown:

```
<?php include "connection.php";

                        $writer_query="SELECT * FROM writer LIMIT 0,5";
                        $run_query= mysqli_query($conn, $writer_query);
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0){
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
                            $wid=$row["w_id"];
                            $wname=$row["w_name"];
                            echo"
                            <a class='nav-link bottom' id='v-pills-profile-tab' data-toggle='pill' href='#v-pills-profile' role='tab' aria-controls='v-pills-profile' aria-selected='false'>$wname</a>
                            ";
                        }}
                        ?>
```

and here is the code where i display the books on the homepage:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-deck">
    <?php include"connection.php";
    $book_query="SELECT b.*, w.* FROM books as b INNER JOIN writer as w on b.b_writer = w.w_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8";
    $run_query= mysqli_query($conn, $book_query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
    $bid=$row["b_id"];
    $bname=$row["b_name"];
    $bisbn=$row["b_isbn"];
    $bwriter=$row["w_name"];
    $bprice=$row["b_price"];
    $bdesc=$row["b_desc"];
    $bimg=$row["b_img"];
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mt-4">
    <div class="card text-center ">
    <img class="card-img-top img-thumbnail img-thumb" src="<?php echo"$bimg";?>" alt="Dune">
    <div class="card-body">
    <h6 class="card-title"><?php echo"$bname";?></h6>
    <footer class="blockquote-footer">By <cite title="<?php echo $bwriter;?>"><?php echo"$bwriter";?></cite></footer>
    <p class="card-text">Price: &#8377; <?php echo"$bprice";?></p>                  
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buy">Buy</a>
    <input type="button"  value="Details" id="<?php echo $row["b_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-primary view_data" />
    </div>          
    </div>      
    </div>
    <?php }} ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried ajax ?

Comment: What do you need help with? HTML (layout), SQL (query), or JavaScript (interaction)?

Comment: I just want to know how can i do it..?

Comment: and i haven't tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to store category id into Anchor Tag. 
Like http://www.example.com/home?cat_id=2

And by using this you can get that category id on another page and get params of url.

Now you need to wrire code and query

```
If(!empty(cat_id)) {

//, HERE IS YOUR QUERY AND RETURN ARRAY

}
```